# Batch parenthesis trouble

Tags: batch-file

I'm new in batch and have made a program that writes a file with the `%num%` variable.
I'm having problems with the sum. Instead of returning `1`, `2` and `3`, it returns `(0+1)`,`((0+1)+1)` and `(((0+1)+1)+1)...`
Here is the code:

```
set num=0
:loop
set num=(%num%+1)
echo test > "%num%".txt
pause

goto loop;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the sum of  two variables in a batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674974/calculating-the-sum-of-two-variables-in-a-batch-script).  

Please search the existing questions before adding one of your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the `/a` parameter to do arithmetics:

```
set /a num=%num%+1
```

shorter:

```
set /a num=num+1
```

even shorter:

```
set /a num+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like below

```
@echo off
set num=0
:loop
set  /a num=%num%+1
echo test > %num%.txt
pause

goto loop;
```