# Batch Coding For loop to create files with different names

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to Batch coding, so please go easy.

Please consider the following code:

```
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,20) DO (break>"C:\New folder\%%G+1.txt")
```

I'm trying to create text files with the above code, but I'm getting 1+1, 2+1, 3+1.. and so on.

Is there a way to not touch the parameters, but to increase the parameter in `%%G+1`? Instead of outputting as a string, it gives me a number.

Please guide me. thanks

**Update:** I tried this code below

```
:MakeTextFiles
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "var=1"
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,20) DO 
(       
    set /a "var=%var%+1" 
    break>"C:\New folder\!var!.txt"
)
EXIT /B
```

But it's not working.

Comment: read again about [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/combining-all-mp4s-in-directory-with-ffmpeg/30284028#30284028) and "The ( must be on the same physical line as the do" from Magoos answer.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. Still new to this. So there might be some errors on syntax.

Comment: yeah - batch syntax isn't consistent and sometimes not very intuitive. Don't mind - the day you don't produce syntax errors any more is far far far away :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal enabldelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,20) DO 
(
    set /a _new=%%G+1
    break>"C:\New folder\!_new!.txt"
)
```

Please see hundrds of articles on SO about `delayedexpansion`

Two problems with your latest change:

The `(` must be on the same physical line as the `do`.

```
set /a var=!var!+1
```

or

```
set /a var=var+1
```

or

```
set /a var+=1
```

`set /a` accesses the run-time value of `var`, `!var!` is the run-time value of `var`, `%var%` is the parse-time value of `var` - the value that it has when the `for` is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need arithmetic addition here, just change the set you loop over:

```
FOR /L %%G IN (2,1,21) DO (break>"C:\New folder\%%G.txt")
```

If you definitely want arithmetic:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,20) DO (
set /a var=%%G+1
break>"C:\New folder\!var!.txt")
```

You need to look here:

[calculating the sum of two variables in a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674974/calculating-the-sum-of-two-variables-in-a-batch-script)

and here
[delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/combining-all-mp4s-in-directory-with-ffmpeg/30284028#30284028)

Comment: I do not want to touch the parameter.

Comment: I added a link to the arithmetic answer.

Comment: additionally you'll need [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: Thank you Stephan, you're right. I amended the answer.