# Calculating the sum of two variables in a batch/UNIX single piped line

Tags: windows, unix, awk, cygwin

I would like to execute some basic mathematical calculations in batch/Cygwin, but the solution, described in [StackOverflow question: Calculating the sum of two variables in a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674974/calculating-the-sum-of-two-variables-in-a-batch-script) is using the `set /A` command for that matter.

This does not suit me, because I'd like to have everything in a pipe (UNIX style, hence the Cygwin).

My idea is the following: I have a list of files, containing an entry. I'd like to show, for all mentioned file, the one line behind that entry.

Therefore I was thinking about following approach:

Find the line where the entry is found: `fgrep -n <entry>` // this shows the line number together with the entry itself
Only show the line number: `fgrep -n <entry> | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'`
Add '1' to that number
Take the first amount of entries : `head -<new number>`
Only take the last line : `tail -1`

But as I don't know how to add 1 to a number, I am stuck here.

I've already tried using `bc` (basic calculator) but my Cygwin installation seems not to cover that.
As I want to have everything within one piped line, the usage of `set /A` has not sence.

Does anybody have an idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can add BC to your cygwin installation by re-running setup and installing it.

Comment: The cygwin package is named "bc": https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=bin%2Fbc&arch=x86_64

Comment: `expr` can be used to do some arithmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, sorry, I just realised that `awk` is capable of doing some basic calculations, so by replacing `{print $1}` by `{print $1 + 1}` my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Bash has builtin support for declaring variables to be integer and for doing arithmetic on integers. Bash has a `help` command and you should have both `man bash` and `info bash` installed.